# How to install Qt.-5.0.2 on ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.10

I've downloaded qt-linux-opensource-5.0.2-x86-offline.run and i cant install it on ubuntu.

this is all i have done.

```
$ cd /media/moslem/0EB40068B400549D/
$ chmod +x qt-linux-opensource-5.0.2-x86-offline.run
$ sudo ./qt-linux-opensource-5.0.2-x86-offline.run
    [sudo] password for moslem:
    sudo: ./qt-linux-opensource-5.0.2-x86-offline.run: command not found
```

please tell me how i can install it.

Comment: Verify that the MD5 hash of the downloaded file matches the one posted on the QT site, there are reports of these files being corrupted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try sudo on all commands...

Comment: yes i must wrote sudo chmod +x qt-linux-opensource-5.0.2-x86-offline.run